# $F$-structure implies regular singularities + unipotent local monodromy?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, connections, frobenius-map

Let $(\mathcal{E},\nabla)$ be a vector bundle with an integrable connection on a smooth quasi-projective $K$ scheme $X$, with $K$ a $p$-adic number field of characteristic $0$. Let $F$ denote a semi-linear lift of the absolute Frobenius on the special fibre, and assume $(\mathcal{E},\nabla)$ has an $F$-structure, i.e. $F^*\mathcal{E}\cong \mathcal{E}$ as $\mathcal{D}$-modules.

Does this imply necessarily that $(\mathcal{E},\nabla)$ has regular singularities at $\infty$, and unipotent local monodromy? Any explanation/reference, or alternatively a counter example would be appreciated.